# In-place Mergesort Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, mergesort, in-place

I'm trying out an in-place mergesort that uses rotation to sort items. The problem is that it works for a power-of-two number of items in descending order and fails for other arrangements or number of items:

```
def binary_search_middle(array, start, middle, end):
    a = 0
    b = min(middle - start, end - (middle + 1)) + 1
    M = (a + b) // 2
    
    while a < b:
        if array[middle - M] > array[(middle + 1) + M]:
            a = M + 1
        else:
            b = M
        M = (a + b) // 2
        
    return M


def rotate(array, start, end, size):
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        array[i], array[i + size] = array[i + size], array[i]


def merge(array, start, middle, end):
    size  = binary_search_middle(array, start, middle, end) + 1
    left  = middle - (size - 1)
    right = (middle + 1) + (size - 1)
    
    while size > 0 and right <= end:
        rotate(array, left, middle, size)
        merge(array, middle + 1, right, end)
        end    = middle
        middle = left
        size   = binary_search_middle(array, start, middle, end)
        

def in_place_merge_sort(array):
    last = len(array) - 1
    size = 1
    
    while size <= last:
        for i in range(0, last + 1, 2 * size):
            middle = i + size - 1
            end    = min(middle + size, last)
            merge(array, i, middle, end)
        size = 2 * size
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In in_place_merge_sort, I don't see any code to handle the case where there is a single run remaining and nothing to merge at the end of a pass, the case where middle >= last. Probably a fix like this:

```
        middle = i + size - 1          # in current code
        if(middle >= last):            # fix
            break                      # fix
```

Comment: Tried, but still getting the same results.

Comment: @PenguinSnow - try something small like a size of 5, 7, or 9 elements and add debugging print statements to see what is happening. I'm not familiar with this version of in place merge sort.